# Having trouble exporting runnable JARs from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

Jar available at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10919879/roller.jar

After writing and testing my program with Eclipse's built-in run Utilities, I decided it was time to export and distribute. So I go to File>Export>Runnable JAR and designate the class whose main method I want to invoke. Everything seems to be going off without a hitch, until I try to actually run the JAR.

Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Users\Matt\Documents\My Dropbox\Publ
ic\roller.jar

Contents of roller.jar

```
dice/Roller$RollData.class
dice/Roller.class
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

contents of META-INF\MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: dice.Roller
```

What's going on, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Make sure you have java env variables set correctly, your classpath is correct (it points to current working dir with your manifest), and in the end rename the file to be Roller.java (notice upper case **R**)

Comment: check whether the path is correct? How did you test it? can your post the command that you tried to test your jar? Open your runnable jar using some archive utility and check if there is the MainClass that you want to execute.

Comment: @CoolBeans
Where do I check my env variables, and what should they look like? How do I know if my classpath is correct? Should I rename it to Roller.java, instead of leaving as Roller.class?

Comment: @prap19 
I think I have the path correct, but I really don't know. To test it, I simply opened a command prompt in the folder containing roller.jar, and entered as a command roller.jar, which yielded 

`Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Users\Matt\Documents\My Dropbox\Public\roller.jar`

As for exploring it with an archive, I have, and the class I want to execute is in the jar, but I don't know how to verify it's correct.

Comment: Try to launch it with `java -jar roller.jar`.

Comment: @mifki That works, thanks! Is there any way I could change the Jar so that the people I distribute it to can run it with a double-click, as little hassle as possible?

Comment: It's not a problem with your jar. It's problem with OS setting that launches jar files incorrectly. I don't know if currently on Windows after installing Java it will be correctly configured automatically and why it isn't on your system. It may require editing registry to set jar files to be launched with `java -jar` command.

Comment: That's nasty... The problem has been replicated on friends' computers, which means it's a common thing... Maybe I should distribute a .bat alongside it

Comment: Yes, .bat file is the easies solution. Also there are many application that convert JARs to EXEs which will be even better for end-users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a problem with your jar. It's a problem with OS setting that launches jar files incorrectly. I don't know if currently on Windows after installing Java it will be correctly configured automatically and why it isn't on your system. It may require editing registry to set jar files to be launched with `java -jar` command.

You can use application that converts JARs to EXEs if you're going to distribute it only to users with Windows.